# user must exist error message in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Getting the error message

> User must exist

when ever I try and create a new post.

I first installed friendly_id gem and then I installed the devise gem and created a devise user model. After that I generated the devise views. From there I created a scaffold for Post with a title description body and slug

I made a `belongs_to :user` in the post model and a `has_many :posts` in the user model. Then I generated a migration that generated this.

```
class AddUserReferenceToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_reference :posts, :user, foreign_key: true
    add_foreign_key :posts, :users
  end
end
```

I know that I can go go into the post model and change it to

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

to get past the error message but I went into the terminal and created a user with

```
u = User.create(email: "dave@gmail.com", password: "password")
```

went to sign in successfully and I still get the error message. Need some help on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please you us your posts controller and the content of your routes.rb file

Comment: I think what you are missing that each of your posts requires a user. So post the posts controller code in you answer. I think you are not defining the user when creating the posts object.

Answer (score 1):

You must change your posts controller, and add this code to the actions new and create.

```
def new
  @post = current_user.posts.build
end

def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the foreign key parameters to permit list:

```
private 
    def posts_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:your_posts_params, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need assossiation between the user  and the post so you  cannot create child without the parent! you need to create user first then you can create post use this in the console irb: User.create!(name: "name", "any other fields") then create post like this irb: Post.create!(text:"some content", user_id: 1) this will create post for the user note assume the user you will create will have id of 1 also sorry this from my phone and will post